# C# Trying to read a file to array and randomly select a line based on test of an integer

Tags: c#, infinite-loop

The solution is meant to read a text file that contains records that consist of three lines. The 1st line of the record is a passing test value, the 2nd line is a question, and 3rd is an answer.

When it executes, it checks if there is just a record or if there is more then one.

The problem is when there are more then one:
It's meant to randomly select a number in the range of amount of records to decide what record. Once it has decided on that record, then the program is meant to see if the random value it generates is in the range of the passing test value matches the passing test value in order to approve the record. All this is meant to run in a while loop until a record is selected, and the random value passes as the passing test value of the record.

I believe it's supposed to work, but when I launch the program it seems to be in an infinite loop as when there are two records it only or when the passing value is two.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Quiz : Form
    {
        Random rnd = new Random(0);
        public Quiz()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            checkFile();
            quizInit();            

        }

        void checkFile()
        {
            if (File.Exists("quiz.txt"))
                MessageBox.Show("Quiz File Exists");
            else
            {
                StreamWriter quizFile = new StreamWriter("quiz.txt");
                quizFile.Close();
            }
        }

        void quizInit()
        {
            string[] quiz = File.ReadAllLines("quiz.txt");
            string question = "";
            string answear = "";
            int lineCount = quiz.Length;
            if (lineCount == 3)
            {
                question = quiz[lineCount - 2];
                answear = quiz[lineCount - 1];
                qLbl.Text = question;
                aLbl.Text = answear;
            }
            if (lineCount > 3)
            {

                bool approved = false;
                int choises = lineCount / 3;
                int selection = 0;
                int check = 0;
                while(approved == false)
                {
                    selection = rnd.Next(1, 2);
                    check = Convert.ToInt32(quiz[selection * 3 - 3]);
                    if(rnd.Next(1,check) == check) approved = true;
                }
                qLbl.Text = quiz[selection * 3 - 2];
                aLbl.Text = quiz[selection * 3 - 1];
                check++;
                quiz[selection * 3 - 3] = check.ToString();
                File.WriteAllLines("quiz.txt", quiz);
            }
        }

        private void newEntryBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(qTxtbx.Text) &&
                string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(aTxtbx.Text)) MessageBox.Show("Fill Both Boxes!");
            else
            {
                StreamWriter quizFile = new StreamWriter("quiz.txt", true);
                quizFile.WriteLine((1).ToString());
                quizFile.WriteLine(qTxtbx.Text);
                quizFile.WriteLine(aTxtbx.Text);
                quizFile.Close();
            }
            quizInit();

        }

        private void newBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            quizInit();
        }
    }
}
```

This is the input:

```
2
q
a
1
q1
a1
```

Comment: How can we check your code if the input is unknown?

Comment: just added input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The max Value specified in Next is Exclusive( https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dx6wyd4(v=vs.110).aspx ) which is why `rns,Next(1,2)` is always 1 and `check` is always 2 because `quiz[0]` is 2. So the last if is never true because `Next(1,2)` is never 2/ Use `Next(1,3)` and it will work

Comment: so if the check is 3 it will the range is 1-2 or for 4 1-3

Comment: Yes `Next(1,2)` = 1 and `Next(1,3)` = 1-2